# Redirecionar usuário para pasta public e restringir acesso aos arquivos da raiz do projeto

Tags: php, mvc, htaccess

Estou fazendo uso de uma estrutura MVC com PHP e, por fins de segurança, meu arquivo index.php que carrega os arquivos de configuração e dá o bootstrap no projeto está dentro da pasta `public/`. Segue abaixo a estrutura de pastas do projeto.

[image: Estrutura de pastas do projeto]

Eu preciso fazer com que quando o usuário acesse o site (como estou em ambiente de desenvolvimento, seria: `http://localhost/estrutura_mvc/`), ele seja redirecionado para o arquivo `public/index.php` e que **esta pasta seja a única acessível para o usuário**. Eu estou conseguindo normalmente fazer o redirecionamento para o arquivo index.php usando o seguinte código no `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Porém, desta forma o usuário tem acesso total a arquivos que estão na raiz do projeto (por exemplo: `http://localhost/estrutura_mvc/.env` retorna o conteúdo deste arquivo sem nenhum tipo de restrição). Como eu faço para que os únicos arquivos que ele tenha acesso seja os que estão na pasta `public/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução. Para resolver, precisa ser criado dois arquivos, um `.htaccess` na raiz do projeto, e um `.htaccess` dentro da pasta `public` (ou a que você quiser que fique o index).

Para fazer o redirecionamento para a pasta `public`, o `.htaccess` na raiz do projeto deve conter o seguinte conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Já o `.htaccess` que está dentro da pasta `public` deve conter o seguinte conteúdo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nome_da_pasta_do_seu_projeto
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Sendo as duas primeiras linhas obrigatórias e o resto você pode customizar de acordo com sua aplicação.

Créditos vão para [Dhairya Lakhera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5702455/dhairya-lakhera) que respondeu [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015013/apache-document-root-using-htaccess) com a solução.